# Comparar números del array con los números random

Tags: javascript

La función del código es comparar los números del array bingolines y compararlos con los generados aleatoriamente y si encuentra el mismo número cambiarlo por una `x`.

He probado varias cosas pero parece como si el `for` no recorriera correctamente el array multidimensional y no encuentra coincidencias, ¿Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? lo demás parece que esta bien pero no encuentra ninguna coincidencia con ningún número. gracias.

```js
let nombre = [];
let randomNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let numberRandom;

let bingoLines = [];
let bingoLine;

let start = 0;
let numbersPerLine = 5;
let lines = 3;
let seguir;
let encontrado;

const nombreJugador = () => {
  do{
  nombre = prompt("Bienvenido al Bingo Skyonline, cual es su nombre ");
  if (nombre !== null) {
      console.log('Bienvenido: ' + nombre)
      bingoCard();
  } else {
      window.alert('Introduzca nombre para continuar ')
  }
}while(nombre == null)
}



let bingoCard = () => {
  
   randomNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

   bingoLines = [];
   bingoLine;

   start = 0;
   numbersPerLine = 5;
   lines = 3;
  

  randomNumbers = randomNumbers.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5 });

  for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      
      bingoLine = [];
      bingoLine.push(randomNumbers.splice(start, 5));
      //console.table(bingoLine);
      

      bingoLines.push(bingoLine);
      
      start = (i * numbersPerLine)-5;
  }
  console.table(bingoLines);
}
nombreJugador();

let pedirTurno = () =>{
  let num1 = 1;
  let num2 = 20;
  //let seguir;

  do {

    seguir = confirm('Desea pasar al siguiente turno?')
    if (seguir == true) {
      numberRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2);
        tacharNumero();
        if (encontrado) {
            console.log("Se ha encontrado el numero: " + numberRandom);
            //cantarLinea();
            //cantarBingo();
            console.table(bingoLines);
        }
        else {
            console.log('El numero: ' + numberRandom + ' no hay coincidencias');
        }
    }

} while (seguir == true);
};

let tacharNumero = () => {
  encontrado = false;
    for(i = 0; i < bingoLines.length; i++){
      for(y= 0; y < bingoLines[i].length; y++)
      
          if (bingoLines[i][y] === numberRandom) {
              bingoLines[i][y] = 'x';
              console.log("Se ha encontrado el numero: " + numberRandom + " en fila " + i + " y columna " + y);
              encontrado = true;
          }
          }
          
  
};
pedirTurno();
```

Comment: Has hecho seguimiento de qué valores estás obteniendo en `numberRandom`? Seguro de que son enteros positivos en el intervalo que deseas?

Comment: son numeros enteros porque cuando no encuentra coincidencias devuelve el numero generado con un mensaje de no encontrado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en la función `tacharNumero()`. Estuve revisando el código y sí, hubo un par de cosas que se te pasaron por alto. El último `for`, por ejemplo, no tenía puesto las llaves. En ese mismo `for` la manera de recorrer el array estaba incompleta: si haces un `console.log` de `bingoLines` vas a ver que cada array dentro de ese array está a su vez dentro de ootro array, así que le agregué el `[0]` entre `[i][y]`. Por eso fallaba. La idea general está bien pero hay que pegarle una buena limpieza al código. Te recomiendo ir haciendo un `console.log` en cada instancia del algoritmo para que tengas una mejor comprensión de lo que sucede y lo lleves a cabo con mejores prácticas. Saludos! 
PD.: Otro tema con los `for` era la condición para finalizarlos. Vos habías puesto `i = array.length`. En el primer `for`, por ejemplo, `i` terminaba valiendo 3 ya que esa es la cantidad de elementos que tiene el array pero la posición de los elementos empieza en 0. Osea que el índex del 3er elemento es [2], ¿Me explico? bingoLines[3] es `undefined`.

```
let nombre = [];
let randomNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let numberRandom;

let bingoLines = [];
let bingoLine;

let start = 0;
let numbersPerLine = 5;
let lines = 3;
let seguir;
let encontrado;

const nombreJugador = () => {
  do{
  nombre = prompt("Bienvenido al Bingo Skyonline, cual es su nombre ");
  if (nombre !== null) {
      console.log('Bienvenido: ' + nombre)
      bingoCard();
  } else {
      window.alert('Introduzca nombre para continuar ')
  }
}while(nombre == null)
}



let bingoCard = () => {
  
   randomNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

   bingoLines = [];
   bingoLine;

   start = 0;
   numbersPerLine = 5;
   lines = 3;
  

  randomNumbers = randomNumbers.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5 });

  for (let i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      
      bingoLine = [];
      bingoLine.push(randomNumbers.splice(start, 5));
      //console.table(bingoLine);
      

      bingoLines.push(bingoLine);
      
      start = (i * numbersPerLine)-5;
  }
  console.table(bingoLines);
}
nombreJugador();

let pedirTurno = () =>{
  let num1 = 1;
  let num2 = 20;
  //let seguir;

  do {

    seguir = confirm('Desea pasar al siguiente turno?')
    if (seguir == true) {
      numberRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2);
        tacharNumero();
        if (encontrado) {
            console.log("Se ha encontrado el numero: " + numberRandom);
            //cantarLinea();
            //cantarBingo();
            console.table(bingoLines);
        }
        else {
            console.log('El numero: ' + numberRandom + ' no hay coincidencias');
        }
    }

} while (seguir == true);
};

let tacharNumero = () => {
  encontrado = false;
    for(i = 0; i < bingoLines.length; i++){
      for(y = 0; y < bingoLines[i][0].length; y++){
           if (bingoLines[i][0][y] === numberRandom) {

              bingoLines[i][0][y] = 'x';
              console.log("Se ha encontrado el numero: " + numberRandom + " en fila " + i + " y columna " + y);
              encontrado = true;
          } 
      } 
          }
        };
        pedirTurno();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, sabia que algo faltaba en el for pero no daba con ello, tomare en cuenta tus consejos.